# Creating hashsets that contain different types of objects

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist, hashset

I have written a program (java sockets) where a multi-threaded server can connect to multiple clients. In order to communicate with a single client, the server program has one `DataInputStream` and one `DataOutputStream` for each client. I want to broadcast a message from the server to the clients one by one. **Each client can respond back differently**. Depending on the response, the server takes it next action. In fact I am trying to find which client contains a certain file. To broadcast the message to all the clients I add the `DataOutputStream` for each client into a HashSet.

```
private static HashSet<DataOutputStream> comChannels = new HashSet<DataOutputStream>();
```

I can iterate through the items in the HashSet to broadcast any message to the clients.
I then broadcast the fileName of the file I am looking for from the server. When a client finds that file in one if its directory it sends a positive response back. If a client does not have that file it sends back a negative response.

The problem I am facing is I cannot get a reply from the clients. When I create a client thread, I create a corresponding `DataInputStream` for the client as well. I tried to create a `HashSet` of `ArrayList` where each `ArrayList` contains the `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` for one single client.

```
HashSet<ArrayList<Object>> comChannels = new HashSet<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

I then create an `ArrayList` containing the input and output stream of a client every time a new client thread is created which I then add to the `HashSet` of `ArrayList`s. I thought i can iterate through the `HashSet` which would return an `ArrayList` in each iteration. I can then select the 1st object of the list and that would be my outputstream and the 2nd object would be my inputstream. But this does not work.

```
for (ArrayList<Object> client  : comChannels) {
        //select outputstream from the Arraylist and write message to client
        //select inputstream from the Arraylist and read response from client
}
```

How can I broadcast and get replies from clients in a way where I can identify which response came from which client? Please note that I want to send the message to one client at a time and terminate the program as soon as a positive response comes back. This saves me from sending the message to all the clients unnecessarily. So creating separate `HashSets` of `DataInputStream`s and `DataOutputStream`s and then writing to all the clients and reading in all the different responses is not feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of streams representing a client is a domain concept in your application and should probably be captured in a meaningful class. Something like this at a bare minimum:

```
public class Client {
    public DataOutputStream outStream;
    public DataInputStream  inStream; 

    public Client(DataOutputStream out, DataInputStream in) {
        this.outStream = out;
        this.inStream = in;
    }
}
```

Whenever you create your streams for a client stick them in an instance of this `Client` class. Then you can put the `Client` objects in a `List` and iterate all you want.

```
for (Client client : clientList) {
    // do whatever you want with client.outStream and client.inStream
}
```

Now you end up with a `List<Client>`, which is much easier for a person to grok than a `HashSet<ArrayList<Object>>`.